# Custom Collation on MySQL Unknown

Tags: mysql, collation

I've created a new collation as per the instructions [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/full-text-adding-collation.html). In fact this tutorial was the exact use-case I needed. I've added the collation, and restarted mysql. When I try to run

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` CHANGE COLUMN `my_column` `my_column` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_fulltext_ci' NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ;`
```

I get the error `Error Code: 1273. Unknown collation: 'latin1_fulltext_ci'`. When I run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS WHERE COLLATION_NAME = 'latin1_fulltext_ci';` I get:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----+------------+-------------+---------+
| COLLATION_NAME     | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | ID | IS_DEFAULT | IS_COMPILED | SORTLEN |
+--------------------+--------------------+----+------------+-------------+---------+
| latin1_fulltext_ci | latin1             | 62 |            |             |       0 |
+--------------------+--------------------+----+------------+-------------+---------+
```

So, I know MySQL is finding it. I've run repair, and check for upgrade on the tables and tried creating new tables, but I keep getting the same error `Error Code: 1273. Unknown collation: 'latin1_fulltext_ci'`.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

**Version details**

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| version                 | 5.1.73-log          |
| version_comment         | Source distribution |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64              |
| version_compile_os      | redhat-linux-gnu    |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an extra space in my collation in the latin1.xml file. Removing that, fixed it!

Comment: An extra space where?

Comment: I do not remember where the space was, as it was 5 years ago.

Comment: Just thinking it would've been helpful to other people with the same problem.